# Gutenberg: import dependency or assign from global variable?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

When developing for the Gutenberg / block editor, I see two methods used in various resources. Let's say I wanted to use i18n

[The Gutenberg handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/internationalization/#how-to-use-i18n-in-javascript) sometimes does it like this:

1. Define `wp-i18n` as a dependency in the `wp_register_script` block.
2. Use `const { __ } = wp.i18n;` in the JavaScript.

But [there is also documentation](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/packages/packages-i18n/) on how to do it like this:

1. Add [`@wordpress/i18n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/i18n) as a dependency.
2. Use `import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';` in the JavaScript.

How do these ways differ and what is considered best practice in WordPress?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `@wordpress/i18n` documentation doesn't assume that it will be used in WordPress, while the Gutenberg handbook documentation is for Gutenberg. So follow the Gutenberg docs if you're developing for Gutenberg seems like a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Valid point. Since asking yesterday I did alot of research and it seems using the global variable is preferred. Should also keep filesize lower. I will probably write up an answer later today or tomorrow, feel free to add your own